# Are WebSphere portlet actions always CSRF protected

Tags: csrf

I noticed that the WebSphere portlet container generates action URLs containing an ID, which seem to change every time I reload the page. Usually action URLs are used as form submission targets.

Examples:

Request 1: /dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/pw/Z7_69901941IO5OB0AMECLLL52F05/act/**id=efQFBpph1jtCw**/330849354665/=/#Z7_69901941IO5OB0AMECLLL52F05

Request 2: /dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/pw/Z7_69901941IO5OB0AMECLLL52F05/act/**id=igQFBpph1jtBg**/330849315800/=/#Z7_69901941IO5OB0AMECLLL52F05

If there is no way to deduce this ID and a new ID is really generated for each render request, portlet action requests would be CSRF protected by default.

My problem is that this is just an observation. I could neither find anything about what those URLs do contain nor if the ID serves as CSRF token.